# How do I find the exponent of a number?

Tags: java

Is there a method in the Java library that I can use to find the exponent of a number?
Example: If I enter 100, then I expect a return value of 2 (since 10<sup>2</sup> = 100). If I enter 10000, then I expect a return value of 4 (since 10<sup>4</sup> = 10000).

Or do I have to keep a counter and keep computing 10<sup>counter</sup> and check if that is my number. If yes return the counter else increment the counter by 1 and repeat.

Comment: This is called logarithm.

Comment: Decimal logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the logarithm:

```
Math.log10(100); //yields 2.
```

Definition from google:

> **Logarithm**: a quantity representing the power to which a fixed number (the base) must be raised to produce a given number.

And the doc comments of [`Math.log10`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10-double-) state:

> Returns the base 10 logarithm of a double value

Answer (score 0):

[Math.log10()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10(double)) is the standard function found in Math library:

> public static double log10(double a)
>
> Returns the base 10 logarithm of a double value. Special cases:
>
> • If the argument is NaN or less than zero, then the result is NaN.
>
> • If the argument is positive infinity, then the result is positive infinity.
>
> • If the argument is positive zero or negative zero, then the result is negative infinity.
>
> • If the argument is equal to 10n for integer n, then the result is n.
>
> The computed result must be within 1 ulp of the exact result. Results must be semi-monotonic.